# qemu virtual machine send desktop switching command to host

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-machine, qemu, virtual-desktop, libvirt

I would like to set up qemu/virt-manager/spice so that I can run a VM full-screen on its own KDE virtual desktop. I have ctrl-alt-{up,down} set up as desktop switching shortcuts, but I need a way to tell the full-screen virt-manager GUI to send these keyboard commands to the host instead of the guest. Is this possible and how would I go about it?

Comment: There's a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1634069).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps that worked for me:

Open "Virtual Machine manager" → Edit → Preferences. Go to "Console" tab and click the "Change" button next to the "Grab keys". Choose any key you like to and at the same time click "OK". Please note that it requires guest restart.

In my case I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. So, when I have my guest open in full-screen mode, for example in workspace 2  and I want to switch to workspace 1 (Host) I just click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then key combination for workspace change (in my case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>"). So basically it's a double <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and a single <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>).